# Loading model using Jeff Lamarches script

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to load 3D model into scene using Jeff Lamarches python script to export 3D model into Objective C header file in Blender.

I'm using Blender version : 2.63a

Got Lamarche's script from here : https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff

What I did

- Installed the script as it is described in instructions
- Opened blender with default cube
- Tried to export Objective C header file of the default 3D

The header file is generated without any vertex data, any idea why this happens ? 
Please provide any reference that might help me to load 3D model into iOS GL context with its texture.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to him about it directly, using Githubs various features. The chances of you finding someone who knows how this particular random script off the Internet works are pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

You must be in edit mode.  Make sure you unwrap the cube and save the png and load it into xcode.  If that doesn't work, also try while in edit mode, click mesh->faces->triangulate faces.